# Power BI - power query editor - combine several rows in a table

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Given this sample raw table (there are some more columns..):

| agg_group | count_% |
| --- | --- |
| CHARGED_OFF | 1.2 |
| DELINQUENT | 1.8 |
| ELIGIBLE | 90 |
| MERCHANT_DELINQ | 7 |
| NOT_VERIFIED | 0 |

How can I transform this table, to create 2 new columns, using either DAX in Power BI Desktop, or in Power Query?

Desired result:

| agg_group | outstanding_principal |
| --- | --- |
| ELIGIBLE | 90 |
| DELINQUENT | 10 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a Power Query sample that does this, paste the following into a blank query to see the steps, based on your sample data:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("JcsxDoAgDIXhu3QmRl3UUaVAEyyRoAsh3P8WNnX93v9qhTPs2aPtyTkwMA0zNFPBYiS+H+SiuCqKeToiCm2jyoVZ/lz638uwqHMq/cVMjtAKStw+", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [agg_group = _t, #"count_%" = _t]),
    #"Cleaned Text" = Table.TransformColumns(Source,{{"count_%", each Number.FromText(_, "en-US"), type text}}),
    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Cleaned Text", "agg_group_", each if [#"agg_group"] = "ELIGIBLE" then "ELIGIBLE" else "DELINQUENT"),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Conditional Column", {"agg_group_"}, {{"outstanding_principal", each List.Sum([#"count_%"]), type text}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{{"agg_group_", "agg_group"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I made small change in the data, if I change the name of the column it doesnt work

Comment: I have updated my answer according to your new sample data.